# Application Pool Exception

Tags: c#-4.0, iis-7.5

I have created WCF to create pool and site to IIS. when I try to use that WCF it gives the following exception.

```
Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool cannot be serialized 
because it does not have a parameterless constructor.
```

Can anyone help please?
Thanks